# Bluetooth connection is not stable with multiple devices(mouse & earbuds) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: bluetooth

I have a problem of multiple pairing via Bluetooth 5.0 on ubuntu 20.04.
Below information is my current environment.

- ubuntu version

```
jinsoo@jspc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

- Info about bluetooth

I'm currently using the bluetooth via USB-A reciever, not installed in motherboard directly.
The chipset of the reciever is RTL8761B, so I already installed the right version of firmware.

```
jinsoo@jspc:~$ dmesg | grep Bluetooth:
[248832.686496] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[248832.687540] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[248832.687551] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[248832.687692] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
[248832.687760] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz -2, total sz 11664
[248832.760574] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x097bec43
[248886.256557] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
```

- What I want to connect simultanously

```
1. Logitech MX matser 3S for mac (bluetooth only)
2. QCY t5 earbuds
```

- What I did before

1. reboot
2. re-install the firmware
3. restart the bluetooth service
4. re-connect both devices

When I connect just 1 device, it works successfully. In  the case of connecting multiple devices(over 2), however, the connection is not stable to both devices. For example, sometimes, the sound and movement of cursor are stuttering at the same time.
The connection of both devices is not stopped but unstable. Thus, I can not catch any errors.

What can I do?
If you need some more information, please let me know. I'll add it asap.

Thank you for your help in advance.